# asp:Updatepanel, trouble with updatepanels as my pages are doing full postback everytime I click on a button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am having a simple page which has two steps:
step 1: create a username and password when I click next button it has to go to step 2: to enter all the information.
When I click the next button, the step 2 page loads and immediately goes back to step 1. I tried putting the update panels around entire step 2 but then it doesnt allow me to click previous button or submit button. I also tried surrounding all my labels and textboxes with update panel leaving the previous and submit button but somehow it did not work too. Please help me out.
Also I have a bootstrap date picker included in this. I dont understand how to get the date entered in that box in code behind.
Here is my code:
Default.aspx

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Template/Main.Master" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="Library._Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
     <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap1-css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" runat="server" media="screen" href="/css/StyleSheet.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" runat="server" media="screen" href="~/css/StyleSheet3.css" type="text/css" />

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <%--<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/JavaScript.js"></script>--%>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/JavaScript1.js"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/> 

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
  <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="" id="loginModal">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                        <h2 class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" id="Heading1"> Welcome! </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="well">
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#Userlogin" data-toggle="tab">User Login</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#ManagerLogin" data-toggle="tab">Manager Login</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#create" data-toggle="tab">Create Account</a></li>
                            </ul>
                              <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                              <div class="tab-pane active in" id="Userlogin">
                              <div class="form-horizontal">
                                <fieldset>
                                     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="uplogin" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                      <Triggers>
                                          <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" EventName="click" />
                                      </Triggers>
                                      <ContentTemplate>
                                  <div class="control-group">
                                      <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" CssClass="col-xs-12" Text="UserName"></asp:Label>
                                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                  </div>
                                           </ContentTemplate>
                                  </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                  <div class="control-group">
                                      <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" CssClass="col-xs-12" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
                                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="control-group">
                                  <div class="controls">
                                      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upLogin2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                          <ContentTemplate>
                                              <asp:button cssclass="btn btn-success btn-block" ID="btnULogin" runat="server" Text="Login"/>
                                          </ContentTemplate>
                                      </asp:UpdatePanel>                                     
                                  </div>
                             </div>
                        </fieldset>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                                   <div class="tab-pane fade" id="ManagerLogin">
                              <div class="form-horizontal">
                                <fieldset>
                                     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                      <Triggers>
                                          <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" EventName="click" />
                                      </Triggers>
                                      <ContentTemplate>
                                  <div class="control-group">
                                      <asp:Label ID="lblMUserName" runat="server" CssClass="col-xs-12" Text="UserName"></asp:Label>
                                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtMUserName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                  </div>
                                           </ContentTemplate>
                                  </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                  <div class="control-group">
                                      <asp:Label ID="lblMPassword" runat="server" CssClass="col-xs-12" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
                                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtMPassword" TextMode="Password" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="control-group">
                                  <div class="controls">
                                      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                          <ContentTemplate>
                                              <asp:button cssclass="btn btn-success" ID="btnMLogin" runat="server" Text="Login"/>
                                          </ContentTemplate>
                                      </asp:UpdatePanel>                                     
                                  </div>
                             </div>
                        </fieldset>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                           <div class="tab-pane fade" id="create">
                              <div class="form-horizontal">
                                <fieldset>
                                     <div class="container">

<div class="stepwizard col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
      <div class="stepwizard-step">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
              <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnstep1" runat="server" CssClass="nav-link active" href="#step-1" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step1" role="tab" title="Step 1" Text="Step 1"></asp:LinkButton>
              </li>
              <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
              <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnstep2" runat="server" CssClass="nav-link inactive" href="#step-2" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step2" role="tab" title="Step 2" Text="Step 2"></asp:LinkButton>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div role="form">
    <div class="row setup-content tab-pane active" id="step-2">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h3>Create Username and Password</h3>
               <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                   <Triggers>
                       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="prevBtn" />
                   </Triggers>
                  <ContentTemplate>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <asp:Label ID="lblCUsername" runat="server" CssClass="col-xs-12" Text="UserName" class="form-control"></asp:Label>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="txtCUsername" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Enter Username"></asp:TextBox>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <asp:Label ID="lblCPassword" runat="server" CssClass="col-xs-12" Text="Password" class="form-control"></asp:Label>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="txtCPassword" TextMode="Password" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Enter Password"></asp:TextBox>
                      </div>
                  </ContentTemplate>
              </asp:UpdatePanel>

            <div>
               <asp:Button ID="prevBtn" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-lg pull-left" Text="Previous" />
               <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg" Text="submit" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>

                      <div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">
                          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
                              <div class="col-md-12">
                                  <h3>Add Information</h3>

                                  <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="conditional">
                                      <Triggers>
                                          <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="nextBtn" />
                                      </Triggers>
                                      <ContentTemplate>
                                           <div class="form-group">
                                              <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="col-xs-12" AssociatedControlID="txtFirstName" class="form-control" Text="FirstName"></asp:Label>
                                              <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"  placeholder="Enter First Name"></asp:TextBox>
                                          </div>
                                           <div class="form-group">
                                              <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" CssClass="col-xs-12" AssociatedControlID="txtLastName" class="form-control" Text="LastName"></asp:Label>
                                              <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Last Name"></asp:TextBox>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                              <asp:Label ID="lblAddress" runat="server" CssClass="col-xs-12" AssociatedControlID="txtAddress" class="form-control" Text="Address"></asp:Label>
                                              <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Address"></asp:TextBox>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                              <asp:Label ID="lblDOB" runat="server" CssClass="col-xs-12"  class="form-control" Text="Date Of Birth" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>

                                              <div class="row">
                                            <!-- Include Bootstrap Datepicker -->
                                            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.min.css" />
                                            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker3.min.css" />
                                            <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                         <div class="col-xs-12 date">
                                         <div class="input-group input-append date" id="datePicker">
                                         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" />
                                           <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                             </div>
                                          <script>
                                             $(document).ready(function() {
                                             $('#datePicker')
                                             .datepicker({
                                             format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
                                               })
                                           .on('changeDate', function(e) {
                                           // Revalidate the date field
                                          $('#eventForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'date');
                                            });

                                          $('#eventForm').formValidation({
                                           framework: 'bootstrap',
                                         icon: {
                                          valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                                          invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                                          validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                                                    },
                                        fields: {
                                             name: {
                                             validators: {
                                             notEmpty: {
                                            message: 'The name is required'
                                             }
                                             }
                                           },
                                       date: {
                                           validators: {
                                           notEmpty: {
                                          message: 'The date is required'
                                                },
                                            date: {
                                        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                                        message: 'The date is not a valid'
                                             }
                                           }
                                        }
                                      }
                                   });
                                  });
                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                              <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" CssClass="col-xs-12" AssociatedControlID="txtEmail" class="form-control" Text="Email"></asp:Label>
                                              <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email"></asp:TextBox>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                              <asp:Label ID="lblPhoneNumber" runat="server" CssClass="col-xs-12" AssociatedControlID="txtPhoneNumber" class="form-control" Text="Phone Number"></asp:Label>
                                              <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhoneNumber" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Primary Phone Number"></asp:TextBox>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                              <asp:Label ID="lblSecondaryNumber" runat="server" CssClass="col-xs-12" AssociatedControlID="txtSecondaryNumber" class="form-control" Text="Secondary Phone Number"></asp:Label>
                                              <asp:TextBox ID="txtSecondaryNumber" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Secondary Phone Number"></asp:TextBox>
                                          </div>
                                      </ContentTemplate>
                                  </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                  <div>
                                  <asp:Button ID="nextBtn" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" Text="Next" />
                                  </div>
                         </div>
                   </div>
             </div>
     </div>
                    </fieldset>
                 </div>
              </div>

                         </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Default.aspx.vb

```
Public Class _Default
Inherits Library.Helper

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        txtUsername.Focus()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub btnULogin_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnULogin.Click
    InitiateULogin()
End Sub
Protected Sub btnMLogin_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMLogin.Click
    InitiateMLogin()
End Sub
Protected Sub btnSubmit_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    InitiateCreateUserName()
    InitiateAdd()
End Sub

Private Sub InitiateULogin()
    Try
        Dim conn As New Connection(Connection.EConnectionString.Library)
        Using conn.Connection
            Actions.ULogin(txtUsername.Text.Trim(), txtPassword.Text.Trim(), "User", conn.Connection)
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Library.Helper.ShowMessage(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub InitiateMLogin()
    Try
        Dim conn As New Connection(Connection.EConnectionString.Library)
        Using conn.Connection
            Actions.MLogin(txtMUserName.Text.Trim(), txtMPassword.Text.Trim(), "Manager", conn.Connection)
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Library.Helper.ShowMessage(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub InitiateCreateUserName()
    Try
        Dim conn As New Connection(Connection.EConnectionString.Library)
        Using conn.Connection
            Actions.CreateUserId(txtCUsername.Text, txtCPassword.Text, "User", conn.Connection)
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Library.Helper.ShowMessage(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Where is the updatepanel?

Comment: I don't see an update panel in your sample code. The update panel need to encapsulate everything that gets updated.

Comment: Sorry I removed the update panel as it was not working. I added it now. Please let me know where I went wrong.

Comment: Can you post your full `aspx` code and `code behind` aswell please?

Comment: added the full aspx and code behind

Comment: There's no `Click Event` on the codebehind for the `nextBtn` control.

Comment: @SantiagoTrejo because i am not doing anything with that button in my code behind. it is used just to move to next step which I handled in .aspx

Comment: @SantiagoTrejo can you please let me know how can i use the date value entered in the datepicker box in my codebehind

Comment: Just add the `runat="server"` tag and give it an `ID`, then you should be able to access it as `date.Value` in your code behind. For the `Step1 - Step2` issue, I would divide Login, Register, etc into separate webforms, for better manageability, simpleness and to preserve `ViewState` as lightest as posible.

Comment: @SantiagoTrejo I will do that. And date.value is working. thank you so much.

Comment: Ok. I invite you to upvote on comments and answers that were helpful to your cause.

Comment: @SantiagoTrejo Please dont mind me asking this but I do not see any upvote option near comments. how do I do that.

Comment: Hover to the left side of any comment, you will see an `Up arrow` and a `Flag` icon. Unless you're not allowed due to your current reputation score.